# Eslint double quotes getting error to fix as single quotes

Tags: javascript, eslint, linter

I am facing issue in " " in ESLinter configuration.

Currently if it is ' ' single quoted no would be found..
But problem with double string quote.

Any luck/ rules for it please help, learner in linter config !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disable [this](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes) rule in your eslint config. You should only be using one type of quotes in your code generally though just for the sake of consistency. This is what the rule would look like in your .eslintrc file:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "quotes": "off"
    },
}
```

Comment: Awesome it works for,

I do not know why people dislike it, making down remark!